# Spring can not find apache commons logging

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, apache-commons

Java 1.8
Spring 5.3.5
Tomcat 9 in Docker

Trying to run Spring app inside apache tomcat in docker container, but Spring fails to initialize:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate     [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandl
erMapping]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  'org.apache.commons.logging.Log 
org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(java.lang.String)' at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225)
```

I have included apache commons into dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-M2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


dependencies {
        implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jcl', version: '5.3.5'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '5.3.5', ext: 'pom'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.3.5'
        implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
        implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.3'
        implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'}
```

I can also see it in when deployed (thats how it looks on the server after deployment in tomcat9):

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Remove all those dependencies and just add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency (no version etc.) which will fix the issue. Your dependencies are a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I hope it will help someone. It turned out that this plugin messed it all up:

```
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
```

It was added by default by Spring initializer web app. After I removed it, everything started to work as it should.

Comment: The actual problem is your inclusion of version numbers for the dependencies (those are managed by Spring BOot) and the inclusion of `commons-logging` as a dependency don't do that. Finally you are mixing jars from different versions 5.3.4 and 5.3.5 of a library/framework which is eventually going to bite you with weird to debug errors.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try it out. I am not sure why it added some 5.3.4 jars, I only have declared dependency on 5.3.5.

Comment: Looking at the dependencies, you probably added a spring boot starter as well. Or manually added libraries to the classpath instead of using gradle.